# CakePHP how to retrieve HABTM data with conditions more efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have the following MySQL query in CakePHP 2.x it works but it takes really long, if I remove the "joins" it works fast, but the 'Tag.tags LIKE' => '%'.$busqueda.'%' part wont work, any ideas of how can I make this to work faster? better said: how can I remove the joins and still be able search on the Tag table?
Its part of a search engine on a intranet
Thank you in advance

```
$year = $this->request->query['year'];
$years = "year(`Saliente`.`fecha_rem`) = ".$year;
$this->loadModel('Saliente');
                $this->Saliente->recursive = -1;
                $busqueda_c = mysql_escape_string($busqueda);
                $this->Saliente->bindModel(
                array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array(
                        'Tag' => array(
                            'className' => 'Tag',
                            'jointable' => 'salientes_tags',
                            'foreignKey' => 'saliente_id',
                            'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );
                $options = array('joins' => array(
                array('table' => 'salientes_tags',
                    'alias' => 'SalientesTag',
                    'type' => 'left',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Saliente.id = SalientesTag.saliente_id'
                    )
                ),
                array('table' => 'tags',
                    'alias' => 'Tag',
                    'type' => 'left',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'SalientesTag.tag_id = Tag.id'
                    )
                )
                ), 'maxLimit' => 300, 'limit' => 10, 'contain' => array('Tag' => array('fields' => array('Tag.tags') )), 
                'fields' => array('Saliente.id', 'Saliente.usuario_id', 'Saliente.codigo', 'Saliente.asunto', 'Saliente.observacion', 
                'MATCH(Saliente.asunto, Saliente.observacion) AGAINST("+'.$busqueda_c.'*") AS relevance'), 'countField' => 'DISTINCT Saliente.id', 
                'conditions' => array($years, 'OR' => array("MATCH(Saliente.asunto, Saliente.observacion) AGAINST('+".$busqueda_c."*')", 
                'Saliente.codigo LIKE' => '%'.$busqueda.'%', 'Tag.tags LIKE' => '%'.$busqueda.'%' )), 
                'order' => 'relevance DESC, 
                fecha_rem DESC', 'group' => 'Saliente.id');

                $this->Paginator->settings = $options;
                $resultado = $this->Paginator->paginate('Saliente');
                $this->set('resultado', $resultado);
```

Comment: Take the SQL-Query. check it with explain (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) and then set indexes where it is needed. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html). But you should know, that searchings with % at the beginning won't work very fast by default.

Comment: thank you for your reply, the indexing its done already, the problem really is the joins, I need a way to be able to remove the joins but still be able to search tags.